# Why is my dryer producing condensation and wet inside when it is not in use?

Tags: dryer, exhaust-fan

During the recent one year, I have noticed my dryer is producing condensation and wet inside when it is not in use. I live in a 5 units apartment building and I am on the top floor. After I cleaned the dryer duct, it still has this problem. I almost feel the hot air comes from my neighbors' apartment and somehow it gets into my dyer when they are laundering.

Maybe the fan getting hot air out of the building for the building common duct is not working? How to identify? What type of contractors should I hire to check this issue?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Do the dryers all connect to a common exhaust shaft, or do they vent to individual terminations in the wall?

Comment: Yeah, this sure sounds like the sort of thing you could get as the top connection to a shared vent.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just spoke with someone and was suggested to install a piece in the duct that I can manually open and shut the duct. When I do laundry, leave it open and shut it off once it is done. That will prevent the hot air from other apartment to come into my duct.

Comment: @Carrie -- IMC 504.11 point 2 prohibits dampers in dryer vent ducts in multidryer installations

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- can you please let me know what does that mean? Thanks again

Comment: @Carrie -- in other words, that somebody's suggestion is no good (think of what'd happen if you tried to run the dryer with the piece-in-the-duct, called a *damper*, closed, and you'll get why building codes (the International Mechanical Code, precisely) prohibit such a thing)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- oh I see. Thanks for letting me know. So, there is no solution at all?

Comment: @Carrie -- btw, are your dryers gas or electric?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- it's gas

Comment: @Carrie -- have you asked building management to look into the situation already?  This sounds *extremely* serious...if you don't have one, get a battery-operated CO detector!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel why is it extremely serious? We don't have a management company and we are self-sufficient.  I have already had a battery-operated CO detector right on above the washing machine.  So far, the detector has never been alarmed.  But, what else can I do to prevent the heat from coming in to my dryer from the common vent? Or, is this absolutely something that can't be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: @Carrie -- because CO can be a real nasty bastard, basically, and there is some evidence that chronic, low-level exposure to it can be harmful